# Rails 3.1.0, geokit, with error acts_as_mappable

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-plugins, geokit

I am getting the

```
undefined local variable or method `acts_as_mappable'
```

error when using geokit, and after tons of Goggling and attempts, I cannot seem to be able correct the problem.

Basically, I have the following gems installed:

```
geokit (1.6.0, 1.5.0)
geokit-rails31 (0.1.3)
```

and have the following in my model

```
class House < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_mappable
end
```

and Gemfile:

```
gem 'geokit', '>= 1.5.0'
gem 'geokit-rails31'
```

I get the error with or without doing the following in my local app.

```
rails plugin install git://github.com/jlecour/geokit-rails3.git
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay - Here is the solution for anyone that needs help on how I got it to work...

Make sure your project Gemfile does not contain any geokit info of any kind.

install geokit

```
> gem install geokit

> gem list geo
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
geokit (1.6.0, 1.5.0)
```

uninstall geokit-rails3 and geokit-rails31

```
> gem uninstall geokit-rails31 geokit-rails3
```

in your project, at the root level:

```
> rails plugin install git://github.com/jlecour/geokit-rails3.git
```

edit the spec

```
> vi vendor/plugins/geokit-rails3/geokit-rails3.gemspec
```

change rails dependency line to be

```
s.add_runtime_dependency 'rails', '>= 3.1.0'
```

now, edit the Gemfile to include the gem

```
gem 'geokit-rails3', :path => 'vendor/plugins/geokit-rails3'
```

Note, the Gemfile only contains an entry for the geokit-rails3, and no entries for normal geokit gem. i.e. there is not a "gem 'geokit', '>= 1.5.0'" entry

then in your application root, do a

```
bundle install
```

It should be setup, and you can now follow a typical tutorial - as described in the git instructions

```
https://github.com/jlecour/geokit-rails3
```