# undefined method `acts_as_mappable' trying to use geokit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, geokit

I am trying to use geokit but I get the following message:

```
undefined method `acts_as_mappable'
```

I have tried the following solutions but nothing has worked so far:
[Rails 3.1.0, geokit, with error acts_as_mappable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537251/rails-3-1-0-geokit-with-error-acts-as-mappable)

I am using rails 3.0.1 and ruby 1.9.2

I have followed the instructions here https://github.com/jlecour/geokit-rails3 but its not working

This is my model:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

acts_as_mappable :default_units => :kms,
         :default_formula => :flat

end
```

and I have this in my gemfile

```
gem 'geokit-rails3'
```

I also have the folder vendor, inside I have a geokit-rails3 folder with the files, one of them named acts_as_mappable. I have tried adding require 'geokit-rails3' in the top of my model but it says no file to load.

I tried both, installing it as a plugin:
    rails plugin install git://github.com/jlecour/geokit-rails3.git
and also by doing gem install (and it is shown when I list all the gems installed)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by reinstalling rails with:

```
sudo apt-get install rails rails-doc rails-ruby1.8
```